# What is the squiggly N shape icon in my text design element and how do I interact with it

Tags: text, figma

I'm quite new to Figma and just learning how to use it. I've copied a template and I'm messing around with it a bit to learn what different elements do.

I'm confused as to what this squiggly N shaped element is called, and how it works (for example, if if I wanted to change the word "Food" to "Meal", is that possible and how is it done? Changing word colour, size ect is clear to me, but changing the text itself is not). Sorry for such a basic question, I'm just not even sure of the correct search term for this thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon means the text has been converted to outlines. When text is outlined it becomes an object made of vector paths. Outlined text is not editable as text. To change it, you'd need to delete it and retype it.

If you look underneath these outlined text objects in the layers panel, you can see there is a hidden layer. Presumably this contains the editable text. You could unhide it, and edit that text.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I found that I can rightclick normal text and select "Outliene Stroke" to get the results I asked about above (With the "Squiggly N" icon). Cheers!